# SQLite JDBC Wrapper and matchinfo()

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, full-text-search

I am trying to use the matchinfo function of sqlite with its second parameter, but it is throwing errors. The Java wrapper I am using the [Xerial](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) wrapper. I am using this query to test matchinfo.

```
SELECT matchinfo(search, 'pcx') AS 'test' FROM search WHERE search MATCH 'a search query'
```

it throws this error,

```
SQL error or missing database (wrong number of arguments to function matchinfo()
```

Any idea why this is happening? [this website](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_2) says the matchinfo has an optional second parameter, and I am using fts4 to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Also, slightly off topic, but matchinfo returns a blob of unsigned integers in the form of a byte array. I can't remember how to convert the byte array into an array of ints (longs since unsigned) in java.

Comment: Once again off topic, but if someone wants to get access to the matchinfo data using Xerial, wrap your function in the Function class, and use this method

https://gist.github.com/1020244

Answer (score 0):

the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar from https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads
fixes your problem.

I did not find any version in Maven. So you have to download the jar manually.

Edit:
It's finally in maven central.

Greets,

Jan